# Program launching incorrectly when using a shortcut

Tags: c#, if-statement, shortcut, system.diagnostics, process.start

When I try to launch my program with a shortcut or Process.Start it is running my if's saying that my files are missing and it is not launching the WPF windows. The picture below is what I am trying to launch via shortcut/`process.start`

```cs
if (!File.Exists(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\Multimanager.dll") && !File.Exists(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\Multimanager.dll"))
{
    MessageBox.Show("You are missing the 'Multimanager.dll' and the 'Updater.dll'. Please re-run the MMInstaller.exe to re-download these files", "Missing files", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Warning);
    Application.Current.Shutdown();
}
else if (!File.Exists(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\Multimanager.dll"))
{
    MessageBox.Show("You are missing the 'Multimanager.dll'. Please re-run the MMInstaller.exe to re-download these files", "Missing files", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Warning);
    Application.Current.Shutdown();
}
else if (!File.Exists(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\Updater.dll"))
{
    MessageBox.Show("You are missing the 'Updater.dll'. Please re-run the MMInstaller.exe to re-download these files", "Missing files", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Warning);
    Application.Current.Shutdown();
}
else
{
    string MMV = Multimanager.MMShared.version().ToString();
    string UV = Updater.UShared.version().ToString();

    var u = new Updater.UpdaterWPF(MMV);
    u.ShowDialog();

    var mm = new Multimanager.UUpdater(UV);
    mm.Show();
    u.Close();
}
```

[image: Code of the app I am trying to launch]

Edit: If I launch the program manually with the .exe it opens fine (Oh and IDK if it being a 64-bit application has anything to do with it)

Edit: This is my process.start `Process.Start(path.Text + "\\Multimanager Launcher.exe");` and the path.text is the directory in the screenshot.
The shortcut was made using the code on this website [here](https://www.fluxbytes.com/csharp/create-shortcut-programmatically-in-c/)

Comment: Please, do not post code as images

Comment: Not being able to see your process.start code makes it difficult, but have you set the working directory to that of where the program resides?    BTW:  Please post your code and not a screenshot.

Comment: Ill post that in a mo

Comment: 1. your first `IF` checks for the same condition 2.try to use `appDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` and not `Environment.CurrentDirectory` 3.post your code as a formatted text and not as a picture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use `Environment.CurrentDirectory` for dealing with DLLs. That's a horrible security flaw. Your application is searching for DLLs in the current directory, rather than the application directory. Hopefully, it's not *loading* them from the current directory, but this is something to be very careful about.

To get the application directory, you can use `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` instead. This will not change depending on the (user configurable!) current directory.

Comment: The AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Directory seems to work, I no longer get the missing files message but the WPF windows dont open, Ill open the app and nothing happens.

Comment: @TristanRead Your application probably relies on the current directory elsewhere too. You just need to look for it. And of course, you can always set the shortcut's "Start in" directory to whatever makes sense. Current directory should be something useful from the user's perspective - e.g. default starting folder for an Open File dialog. Application directory should be related to the needs of your application - readonly, with DLLs, configuration files, resources, whatever.

Comment: This works, thanks for pointing out the 'Start In' bit of the shortcut, setting the `shortcut.WorkingDirectory` (Start In) in the shortcut works, the app now opens ;)

Comment: @TristanRead Good for you :) But you should still investigate why. For anything the application itself needs (as opposed to what the user needs), the current directory shouldn't be used. Especially if it involves loading executable code, configuration, passwords or some such - changing the current directory is something every user can do, so you need to be careful about what depends on current directory.

Comment: Yea, exec if I get some code that works I always want to understand why that works and why the other methods didn’t so I can use it for other things